# Passing a individual arguments AND a Seq to a var-arg function

Tags: scala, variadic-functions

I know it's possible to pass individual arguments to a vararg function and it's possible to pass a seq using `:_*` but is it possible to pass both?

for example:

```
scala> object X { def y(s: String*) = println(s) }
defined module X

scala> X.y("a", "b", "c")
WrappedArray(a, b, c)

scala> X.y(Seq("a", "b", "c"):_*)
List(a, b, c)

scala> X.y("a", Seq("b", "c"):_*)
<console>:9: error: no `: _*' annotation allowed here
(such annotations are only allowed in arguments to *-parameters)
       X.y("a", Seq("b", "c"):_*)
                             ^
```

**Edit:** In Scala 2.10 (in case that matters)

Comment: Could you just do `X.y("a" +: Seq("b", "c") : _*)`?

Comment: If the first argument is being implicitly converted to the correct type then this solution doesn't work, any ideas?

http://www.scalakata.com/5148dd4ee4b0d323913d1cd6

Answer (score 5):

Hacky but this should work well:

```
X.y(Seq("a") ++ Seq("b", "c"):_*)
```

Answer (score 3):

If you look around in the Scala standard library you'll find this sort of pattern in places:

```
def doIt(arg: Thing)
def doIt(arg1: Thing, arg2: Thing, moreArgs: Thing*)
```

You can see this, e.g., in `Set.+(...)`. It allows you to have any number of arguments without ambiguity in the overloads.

**Addendum**

Proof of concept:

```
scala> class DI { def doIt(i: Int) = 1; def doIt(i1: Int, i2: Int, iMore: Int*) = 2 + iMore.length }
defined class DI

scala> val di1 = new DI
di1: DI = DI@16ac0be1

scala> di1.doIt(0)
res1: Int = 1

scala> di1.doIt(1, 2)
res2: Int = 2

scala> di1.doIt(1, 2, 3)
res3: Int = 3

scala> di1.doIt(1, 2, List(3, 4, 5): _*)
res4: Int = 5
```

Comment: @om-nom-nom: Untrue, as demonstrated.

Comment: The `Set` factory does not have this overload pattern. When I mentioned `Set` I was actually looking at its `+` methods.